# use onActivityResult method in custom view

Tags: android, custom-controls, onactivityresult

I have a custom view that extends LinearLayot and it has one button and one edit text. i want when user clickes on button, contacts book will open and when user selects a number, the number will show in edit text. i used this code:

```
private void pickContact() {
    Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts"));
    pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); // Show user only contacts w/ phone numbers
    startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
}

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Uri contactUri = data.getData();
             String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};

             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                     .query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();

             int column = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
             String number = cursor.getString(column);

         }
     }
 }
```

Because my class extends LinearLayout, i can't use onActivityResult method. can any body hel me?
tahnks

Comment: why dont you add your custom view to the activity first?

Comment: how can i add custom view to the activity?

Comment: What is the name of the activity, the onActivityResult can be overridden in activity class. Can you please include class declaration where this code belongs. You must be extending Activity class rather then LinearLayout.